# Show / hide DIV on window.location URL

Tags: jquery, html

I need to show hide navigation based on the window location URL.

I have tried this below method, but it didn't work.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var locate = window.location;

        $('#yahooNav, #googleNav').hide();

        if (locate.indexOf("hrpassport-dev.bns") == 0) {
            $('#googleNav').show();
        } else if (locate.indexOf("hrpassport-uat.bns") == 0) {
            $('#yahooNav').show();
        }
   });
</script>

</head>

<body>


    <ul id="googleNav">
        <li>
           <a href="http://www.google.com/glo/glo/english/ss/benefits/highlights/player.html" title="2014 Plan Highlights" target="_blank">2014 Plan Highlights </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com/glo/glo/english/ss/benefits/enrolments/player.html" title="How to Prepare for Enrolment" target="_blank">How to Prepare for <br />Enrolment</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="yahooNav">
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/glo/glo/english/ss/benefits/highlights/player.html" title="2014 Plan Highlights" target="_blank">2014 Plan Highlights </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/glo/glo/english/ss/benefits/enrolments/player.html" title="How to Prepare for Enrolment" target="_blank">How to Prepare for <br />Enrolment</a>  
       </li>
    </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var locate = window.location.href;
```

instead of `var locate = window.location;`

There is ***no*** `window.location.indexOf` since `location` has no method `indexOf`. Where as `window.location.href` gives you the URL address string of your current window.

EDIT:

Also, `locate.indexOf("hrpassport-dev.bns") == 0` checks if the url begins with the text, you have check like this `locate.indexOf("hrpassport-dev.bns") > -1` to check if it contains in the URL.

Comment: Hi, I have tried making the above mentioned changes, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user3203089 - Any console error? Did you include jquery properly. What does `console.log(window.location.href)` give you?

Comment: Below is the error.


Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Thu, 16 Jan 2014 15:56:49 UTC


Message: Object expected
Line: 8
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://hrpassport-dev.bns/HRPassIIS/CanadianBenefitsPlan_Communication/Untitled-4.html

Comment: @user3203089 - try `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">` instead of just script tags.

Answer (score 0):

you just can use

```
var locate = location.href;
```

here a working fiddle
**http://jsfiddle.net/rpCC6/**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is twofold, one of which was already mentioned: `window.location.href` instead of `window.location`. The second is the use of `indexOf`:

```
if (locate.indexOf("hrpassport-dev.bns") > -1) {
    $('#googleNav').show();
} else if (locate.indexOf("hrpassport-uat.bns") > -1) {
    $('#yahooNav').show();
}
```

`indexOf` returns the **location** of the string provided ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to show what I mean), and unless your `window.location.href` begins with that string, it will not be true. By setting it to be `> -1`, you are basically saying "does it exist in the string".